# Rails content_tag on ul with an iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a text field that user's put in data that I'm converting to list items. So they may enter in the text area:

```
Apple
Tomato
Wrench
```

So I have the following that works:

```
 <% regional_services = @region.services.split("\n") %>
  <ul>
   <%regional_services.each do |services| %>
    <li><%=services%></li>
   <%end%>
  </ul>
```

It outputs correctly with something like

- Apple
- Tomato
- Wrench

But I'm trying to get it to work in a helper instead since it's ugly in the view.

So I have the following:

```
def other_service
  if @region.services.present?
    something = @region.services.split("\r\n")
    content_tag(:ul) do
      content_tag(:li, something.each {|alpha| alpha })
    end
  else
    content_tag(:p, 'Here is text')
  end
end
```

It ends up outputting like:

- ["Apple", "Tomato", "Wrench"]

So it looks like it's not applying the iteration on the list item so I tried the following:

```
def other_service
 if @region.services.present?
   regional_service = @region.services.split("\n")
   content_tag(:ul) do
     regional_service.each do |service|
       content_tag(:li, service)
     end
   end
 else
   content_tag(:p, 'Here is text')
 end
end
```

No error but it's actually not displaying anything on the pages that actually have items. So how do I do a content_tag ul with an iteration?

Comment: Use `concat`: `...each do |service| concat content_tag(...); end`

Comment: Welp...that was the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each` returns the array, so the block of `content_tag :ul` is going to receive an array itself as an inner HTML. Which is apparently not what you wanted.

In order to add HTML to an output buffer, you would use [`concat`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat):

```
content_tag :ul do
  regional_service.each do |service|
    concat content_tag(:li, service)
  end
end
```